# Neo4j - Get a list of nodes shared by two nodes as an edge property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two types of nodes.

1. Individual
2. Product

My main edge is

```
(i:Individual)-[:BUYS]->(p:Product)
```

For example,

```
(BOB)-[BUYS]->(MILK)
(BOB)-[BUYS]->(APPLES)
(SAM)-[BUYS]->(BEER)
(LAURA)-[BUYS]->(MILK)
(LAURA)-[BUYS]->(APPLES)
```

I want an edge that is

```
(BOB)-[BUYS_THE_SAME_THINGS_AS {shared_products: [MILK, APPLES]}]-(LAURA)
```

Creating the edge is pretty simple

```
MATCH (i1:Individual)-[b1:BUYS]->(p:Product)<-[b2:BUYS]-(i2:Individual) WHERE (i1.name <> i2.name)
MERGE (i1)-[BUYS_THE_SAME_THINGS_AS]-(i2)
```

What I would like is to set as an attribute of the relation [BUYS_THE_SAME_THINGS_AS] the array [MILK, APPLES]

In this example it is simple because I know it is milk and apples. But let us say I am doing it over 50K individuals and 100K products... I want that for each pattern matched, it will append the product name to the things array in the edge property

But I am new to Cypher and cannot find how to do it.
So if anyone has any insights, I would be glad to hear

Comment: In general, adding redundant data to the DB is bad practice, since it tends to overcomplicate the data model and make the coding much harder. You have to ensure that redundant information is always kept in sync whenever you add/update/delete relevant data. And if you have concurrent DB requests, you have to make sure the data-syncing is done atomically.

Comment: thank you really much. Yes I know I dont want to add to many edges type it is already explosing. But add meta data on the edges is something different no? Just asking...

Comment: You don't need to add any new relationships or store any extra data. For example, if you want to see who buys the same things as individual "a", just do this: `MATCH (i1:Individual {name: 'a'})-[:BUYS]->(:Product)<-[:BUYS]-(i2:Individual) RETURN DISTINCT i2`.

Comment: You are totally right, but let us say I want my users to be able to "walk" in the graph, I wanted them to have some meta data on the edge withtout having to expand it
But thank you really much !!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "walk" the graph. But I suspect you can do that just by using a properly crafted Cypher query (without needing anything extra).

Answer (score 1):

To add properties to your new link, you could go with the following

```
MATCH (i1:Individual)-[b1:BUYS]->(p:Product)<-[b2:BUYS]-(i2:Individual)
WHERE (i1.name <> i2.name)
MERGE (i1)-[l:BUYS_THE_SAME_THINGS_AS]-(i2)
ON CREATE set l.things=[p.name]
ON MATCH set l.things=l.things+p.name
```

Comment: No but here in the example I know it is milk and apples. 

But let us say I am doing it over 50K individuals and 100K products...
I want that for each pattern matched, it will add the product name to the things array in the edge property

Comment: Ok, I edited the Cypher query, supposing that Product nodes have a "name" property